# Can I make a carousel with php and mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, carousel

Do you think it is impossible? I want go get pictures from  mysql database and make a carousel looking like this. >> http://blog.tmimgcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/demos/coding-a-responsive-horizontal-posts-slider-using-css3-and-jquery/index.html
But I want to use only html, css, php and mysql.

Comment: No, I don't think this is possible without JavaScript.

Comment: there are ready made codes available for carousel slider... Just create things dynamic by creating database connection and get data from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofcourse possible...PHP codes will bear the load of javascript functionalities.

Comment: I think it is possible too and I really want to learn it.  What functions of php will u use for it?

Comment: The needed codes & functions only.. can't give you number of functions

Comment: I did it! :)  I can post you codes if you want to.